# Why is the imageview returning null or not retrieving the selected photo from gallery? (Xamarin VS 2015 Android)

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

This is stressing me out for almost a day already because I cannot seem to figure out why the image isn't showing up after I select an image from the gallery (of my android phone). It only gives me a full blank photo without the actual image although the tools (button, textview, etc.) below the image move down. I based my code here [Selecting a Gallery Image](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/files/selecting_a_gallery_image/) and in other threads but still gives me a null.

Here are my codes:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false"/>
```

Main.axml

```
<ImageView
            p1:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
            p1:layout_height="300.0dp"
            p1:id="@+id/imageView1" />
<Button
            p1:text="Attach a photo"
            p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
            p1:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            p1:id="@+id/button1" />
```

MainActivity.cs (I omitted some unrelated codes to my question.)

```
public static readonly Int32 REQUEST_CAMERA = 0;
public static readonly Int32 SELECT_FILE = 1;
private ImageView _imageView;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            if (IsThereAnAppToTakePictures())
            {
                CreateDirectoryForPictures();

                Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
                _imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
                button.Click += ButtonOnClick;
            }
        }

private void ButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            String[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library", "Cancel" };

            using (var dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this))
            {
                dialogBuilder.SetTitle("Add Photo");
                dialogBuilder.SetItems(items, (d, args) => {
                    //Take photo
                    if (args.Which == 0)
                    {
                        TakeAPicture(sender, eventArgs);
                    }
                    //Choose from gallery
                    else if (args.Which == 1)
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick, MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri);
                        intent.SetType("image/*");
                        intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
                        StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_FILE);
                    }
                });

                dialogBuilder.Show();
            }
        }

protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
                {
                    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
                    Android.Net.Uri contentUri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(App._file);
                    mediaScanIntent.SetData(contentUri);
                    SendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

                    // Display in ImageView. We will resize the bitmap to fit the display.
                    // Loading the full sized image will consume to much memory
                    // and cause the application to crash.

                    int height = Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels;
                    int width = _imageView.Height;
                    App.bitmap = App._file.Path.LoadAndResizeBitmap(width, height);
                    if (App.bitmap != null)
                    {
                        _imageView.SetImageBitmap(App.bitmap);
                        App.bitmap = null;
                    }

                    // Dispose of the Java side bitmap.
                    GC.Collect();
                }
                else if ((requestCode == SELECT_FILE) && (data != null))
                {
                    Android.Net.Uri uri = data.Data;
                    _imageView.SetImageURI(uri);
                }
            }

        }
```

*I posted this earlier in Xamarin's forum but they don't seem to know either(?) or my question is vague(?).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `_imageView` that you defined at the `Activity` class level is `null` within the`OnActivityResult` method .

You can to set it via:

```
_imageView = FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.imageView1);
```

Also you can use the `data.Data` from the `Intent` parameter directly as a Uri and do not have to create another Uri object to hold it.

#### Try this code:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
   base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   _imageView = FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.imageView1);

   if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
   ...

   else if ((requestCode == SELECT_FILE) && (data != null))
   {
        _imageView.SetImageURI(data.Data);
   }
```

Comment: I did this but still gives me a blank photo. Taking a photo from camera works like charm but this one gives me headache because it seems so easy to solve but somehow it doesn't work.

Comment: You code works for me after I assigned the `_imageView` var. If you set a breakpoint on `_imageView.SetImageURI(data.Data);` is _imageView assigned? is `data.Data` a Url (beginngin with something like `content://...`?

Comment: I'd like to say that I'm a total noob here but what do you mean data.Data Url? Is it the Android.Net.Uri Intent.Data?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to view the contents in the debugger, is it assigned? Is also _imageView also assigned at that point in your code?

Comment: I think I found what is causing the problem. This shows after I pick an image: 04-20 08:11:57.007 W/OpenGLRenderer(12466): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture

Comment: Ah... that will do it... that device does have much ram on it? 1MB?

Comment: I already have bitmap function that sets the width and height for camera (it's in my codes above). How can I use it for the gallery?

Comment: Yes, pretty cheap phone I don't use anymore.

Comment: While, since that is a GLOpen texture fault, I would try load the images into a stream and creating a lower sampled version of it. Android has a `BitmapFactory` that can assist in that process.

Comment: I just found out that the android phone I'm using only has 512MB of RAM.

Comment: Ouch, that is a small in today's world. The Xamarin/Mono runtime size (in debug mode) is not helping either.

Comment: Maybe I should just buy a new android phone just for the purpose of this. Anyways, I'll try implementing your suggestion to see if it can work even if my phone has very small ram. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, happy coding... ;-)